# AngularJS: change part of html in template (for directive)

Tags: angularjs

I copied this somewhere:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('ffInclude', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile' ,function($http, $templateCache, $compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var templatePath = attrs.ffInclude;
      $http.get(templatePath, { cache: $templateCache }).success(function(response) {
        var contents = element.html(response).contents();
        $compile(contents)(scope);
      });
    };
  }]);
```

The point of this directive is work like ng-include but without creating a new scope.

It can be used like this:

```
<div ff-include="my-template.html"></div>
```

My question is as follows: I would like to use this also for a general template, and in this template I would like to switch out something (an attribute of a html-element).

So if I have this html:

```
<div ff-include="my-general-template.html" new-attribute-value="false"></div>
```

And the template could look like this:

```
<div ng-show="true">Here is some general content</div>
```

In the directive I should get the attribute like this:

```
var newAttributeValue = attrs.newAttributeValue;
```

But how to swap this with new attribute with whatever value is in the ng-show attribute in the template?

**Edit:** I made a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BJRp93?p=preview)...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UxVbTq0Ik7VcTEzWNTxB?p=preview

Comment: set it to true above, i set it to false.

Comment: Oh, @NoypiGilas, completely forgot one thing, this creates a new scope, and the entire reason for the directive was to keep the original scope. Is there a way to do this without creating a new scope?

Comment: was this the question deleted yesterday?

Comment: @NoypiGilas, I was doing many things too quickly yesterday...

Comment: this is not a silly question, actually this is a tricky and useful to someone. the problem is me putting it in the comments instead of the answer section below. i was just playing around answering questions -- sorry if it brought the wrong message.

Comment: if your question is a new scope. actually you are using a feature which isolates a scope. that is the 'scope' configuration in your directive definition object. This feature should create a new isolated scope. if you wanted the original scope, not isolating the scope is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like how this idea of doing general templating... =)

The solution below will not isolate the scope.
http://plnkr.co/edit/jFj8MHZ9Kalrk4qO35IX?p=preview

```
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.newAttributeValue = attrs.newAttributeValue;
    console.log("new=", scope.newAttributeValue);
```

at the general template:

```
 <div ng-show="newAttributeValue">
```

Comment: This is perfect, @NoypiGilas, it was really simple! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: glad to have help. =)